# Solution to the SVM problem

Tags: svm

in support vector machines the idea is to find a decision boundary in which the margin is maximized. This can be written as $$ \text{minimize} \  \lVert w \rVert$$ $$\text{subject to} \ \ y_{i}(\boldsymbol{x}_i \cdot \boldsymbol{w}+b) \geq 1$$

What is the optimal decision boundary based on the above minimization problem. I know that this is a quadratic programming problem and various techniques can be used to solve it. But how would you formulate the optimal decision boundary using the above variables?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "actual" solution.

Comment: @whuber: What is the optimal decision boundary based on the above minimization problem?

Comment: Why don't you [search our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svm?sort=votes) for [tag:svm]? This question has been explicitly answered--with working code and illustrations--in several threads.